# Mapping forward/back mouse buttons in Ubuntu Files

Tags: 16.04

I'd like to bind my thumb buttons on my mouse to `forward` and `back` in ubuntu `Files` program. I'm surprised that this isn't fixed automatically.

Where in the options may I fix this?

Comment: For my Logitech MX Pro mouse the forward and back buttons worked automatically in Chrome for web pages. Do yours work there?